# Vue Google Maps Undefined Errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning to calculate the distance between two points using Google Maps and Vue.js. I am trying to get some initial code working for testing but continually come across errors like: TypeError: Cannot read property 'LatLng' of undefined

I am struggling to working out why vue wont use 'Google' or 'Geometry' for such a simple process. I have referenced 'Geometry' in Main.js, but no luck. I think i am referencing google correctly based on other reading, but I am learning so who knows.

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div><button class='btn-primary' @click='filt'>Filter</button></div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';
export default {
  name: "Distance",
    data: () => {
        return {
          placeholder: "enter location",
            center: {lat: 34.503441, lng: -82.650131},
      targetLoc: { lat: 11.31, lng: 123.89 },
      
        } //ends return
    }, //end data
    methods: {
           filt () {
   
       this.center =  new VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi.maps.LatLng(-36.874694, 174.735292) 
        this.targetLoc = new VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi.maps.LatLng(-36.858317, 174.782284) 
        let distance = VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.center, this.targetLoc) 
      console.log(distance)
      
    },

    },
}
</script>
```

Main.js extract

```
libraries: 'places,drawing,geometry',
```

The code above produces console error: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'LatLng' of undefined"
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your setup to this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div><button class='btn-primary' @click='filt'>Filter</button></div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';
export default {
  name: "Distance",
    data: () => {
        return {
          placeholder: "enter location",
          center: {lat: 34.503441, lng: -82.650131},
          targetLoc: { lat: 11.31, lng: 123.89 },
        }
    },
    computed: {
       google: VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi
    },
    methods: {
       filt () {
          this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy().then(() => {
             this.center = new this.google.maps.LatLng(-36.874694, 174.735292) 
             this.targetLoc = new this.google.gmapApi.maps.LatLng(-36.858317, 174.782284) 
             let distance = new this.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.center, this.targetLoc) 
             console.log(distance)
          });
       },
    },
}
</script>
```

`this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy().then(()` makes sure that the gmap object is ready to use and `computed: { google: VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi },` makes code cleaner